# Call function defined in IIFE through Blazor JSInterop

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, blazor

I have this IIFE attached on window that I plan to use in Blazor server app:

```
window.__rect = (function (placeHolder) {
    function draw(){console.log('Hello world')}
    return { 
        draw: draw
    }
})($('#div-rect'))
```

Is there any way to call __rect.draw() in this IIFE using Blazor JSInterop same as I would do it regularly for ex. by using the Chrome developer tools?

Comment: You should be able to call draw using JSInterop - did you get an error?